# Make div fixed on page scroll in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I currently have a screen layout like this

[image]

I have to render componene 2 inside component 3 in below way

[image]

Due to certain restrictions i cannot put angular component 3 inside angular component 2

so what i have done is to use css to achieve the desired effect

```
.component3 {
    position: relative;
 z-index: 1
}

.component2 {
   position: absolute;
  margin-left: calc(100% - 169px);
  margin-top: 13px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

I have achieved the desired output
however
once user scrolls page the component 2 keeps showing on page. It is not supposed to scroll

what can i do for it ?

Comment: You can try `position: sticky`. https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Comment: Can you put component 3 inside component 2?

Comment: @JensAlenius No .. thats the restriction

Comment: Then please update you question. You wrote: Due to certain restrictions i cannot put angular component 2 inside angular component 3. Then it should be the other way around?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz when i put postion: sticky and bottom: 0 it does stick.. but requirment is not met.. the comp2 is not getting overlapped on comp 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to position component 2 absolutely wrt component 1 and transform the origin to make it stick to the bottom edge as

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
transform: translate(0, 100%);
right: 0;
```

Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/xkmqy8Lh/